# Can MySQL cluster be used as a persistent storage solution?

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, in-memory

According to the MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual, "MySQL Cluster is a technology that enables clustering of in-memory databases in a shared-nothing system", and "MySQL Cluster tables are normally stored completely in memory rather than on disk".

Does this mean that MySQL Cluster is not suitable for a persistent data storage solution?

Comment: I think your information is out of date. [From the 5.7 manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-mysql-cluster.html#faq-cluster-what-memory-needed-cluster): " 
Formerly MySQL Cluster was in-memory only. MySQL 5.1 and later also provide the ability to store MySQL Cluster on disk. (Note that we have no plans to backport this capability to previous releases.) See [Section 19.5.13, “MySQL Cluster Disk Data Tables”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-disk-data.html), for more information."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not exactly about programming